# Real time checking of 2 QLineEdits text

Tags: python, pyqt, qlineedit

I have just started out learning Python and PyQt coding.
Pardon me in advance if my code looks too simplified or 'noobish'.

Currently I have 2 `QLineEdits` widgets - `input01` and `input02` in my UI in which I am trying to check the inputs.

If the texts in `input01` and `input02` are the same, the text lettering will be colored red. Otherwise it will be white.

I did managed to achieved this with the following code:

```
def connect_signals(self):
    self.input01.textChanged.connect(self.sync_inputs)
    self.input02.textChanged.connect(self.sync_inputs)


def sync_inputs(self, text):
    if self.input01.text() == self.input02.text():
        self.input01.setStyleSheet("color: red")
        self.input02.setStyleSheet("color: red")
    else:
        self.input01.setStyleSheet("color: white")
        self.input02.setStyleSheet("color: white")
```

While my above code does works in a real-time scenario, I am wondering if there is a 'detection' or some sort within PyQt or a better checking condition that I can implement or better refine my code?

If not, is my above code good enough?

Comment: it is correct, it is simple, it is fast, it is readable, what else do you want ?, for a simple task it would not seek to optimize personally. :)

Comment: Oh okay, I asked as I thought that there may be some PyQt commands catered for this. I was pretty unsure if this is the 'best' way or not. Glad to hear it is :)

Comment: If you want to improve code here is not the best place, better do it at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, that is a community specialized in those topics.